# VueJs, Jest, Sinon: How do I properly unit test nested functions?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, sinon

So I am trying to understand how to properly unit test my functions that call firebase in them. I want to stub or spy on these firebase functions to just see they are called but not having the actual firebase call go out since that would be more of an integration test by my understanding. I don't quite know the right way to go about this.

This is a VueJs application using Jest with Sinon for testing.

This is a function from one of my Vue components.

```
-Login.Vue-

login() {
      this.performingRequest = true // initialized as false
      firebase.auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          this.loginForm.email,
          this.loginForm.password
        )
        .then(user => {
          this.$store.commit("setCurrentUser",  user.user);
          this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserProfile");
          this.performingRequest = false
          this.$router.push("/mainPage");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          this.performingRequest = false
          this.errorMsg = err.message
        });
    },
```

My test

```
describe('Login.vue', () => {

    const wrapper = shallowMount(Login);

    test('Login function works as expected', () => {

        expect(wrapper.vm.performingRequest).toBe(false); // passes

        let spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.vm.login());
        spy.call();

        expect(wrapper.vm.performingRequest).toBe(true);  // passes

        expect(spy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
        // expect(wrapper.vm.performingRequest).toBe(false);  // passes
    })
});
```

What I want to do is see that the firebase auth function got called and that the values it effects actually got changed.

Trying to understand what to stub / spy on has been difficult. Any help in understanding this process would be much appreciated because I have a lot more of this application to test :D

Thank you for your help in advanced and let me know if I need to provide more information for clarities sake.

In the meantime I will be researching :)

EDIT:

Seems it was just user error on my part. Hope this can help someone!

This did the trick -

```
 const stub = sinon.stub(fb.auth, 'signInWithEmailAndPassword').resolves('returning promise');
```

Comment: have you checked [`firebase-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-mock) package?

Comment: @skyboyer Not yet. I was wanting to focus more on how to properly spy and or stub these nested functions which happen to be firebase methods.

Comment: @skyboyer Think I figured it out. I knew it was just a matter of time till I got it! Also it was just user error heh heh
This did the trick:

const stub = sinon.stub(fb.auth, 'signInWithEmailAndPassword').resolves('returning promise');